# Stack Exchange blog section missing from the Blogs main page

Tags: support, blog

Stack Exchange blog section is missing from the https://stackexchange.com/blogs main page. There used to be a dedicated section for 'Stack Exchange Blog' at the top along with links to five most recent blog posts before the 'community blogs' section.

Here is a screenshot obtained from [Google cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:TpcaPTByidQJ:stackexchange.com/blogs%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us)

> [image]

I can access the SE Blog direct by visiting: http://blog.stackexchange.com but it would be be nice to have the SE Blog section (as shown above in the screenshot) at the of Blog's main page too. Could this be restored?

**P.S.**

Upon doing view source (Google Cache page) I see a `<div class="se-blog">` for the SE Blog links section which is *missing* from the new main page.

Comment: @random can you please explain why the removal of UPDATE?

Comment: Why would that not be the resolution/answer and why would it need to be the first paragraph of a support question?

Comment: @random I have seen other users doing that but if it is wrong then at least you could have post a comment. I'm still learning here. Thank you. So what should I do next?

Comment: @HackerKarma I didn't really see a problem with it being in the question,  and the question getting closed. But maybe, technically or accurately, random is right, it's a question and your update is more suited as an answer. Go post your "answer" :)

Comment: @James That's what I learned here. I did post an answer as "community wiki" user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been resolved in the latest build 2015.9.14.2711. Thank you for fixing it!

Originally I posted this in my question but high-rep user 'random' (and 'Super User' moderator) removed it. See his comment under my post. So, posting an answer instead.

Comment: Why would you answer this? Sheesh, some people..

Comment: @James I didn't get you... I thought it would be silly to post one liner 'update' as an answer. But I can opt my answer to 'community wiki' user right? If not, please let me know I can delete it.

Comment: I was just joking, as I suggested you post an Answer, and then questioned you posting an answer. I admit it wasn't "hilarious", but I thought it slightly amusing, well had you got it :D